# DataGrid Sort/Update Issue

Tags: wpf, sorting, wpfdatagrid

My app as it initiates it populates a DataGrid with data retrieved from a Data Base. My fields are: Name, ID and Status. The first two no problem, but the third one (Status) is an int, either 1 or 0, indicating active or inactive.

I decided to create an User Control to show the "Status" field. It's nothing more than a circle wich turns green or red depending on the value of "Status". The default color of the control is red.

I also created a list object("data") that contains my information plus the control with it's respective color. So far no problem. Everything works, and if I do a quick watch on my data object, everything is as it should be.

My problem is that after I populate the DataGrid with "myDataGrid.ItemsSource = data", every control "Status" appears as red, when some of them should be green. If I breakpoint at any given time and quick watch my "data" object, everything is fine, but the DataGrid does not update.
The same happens for sorting. If I change the color of any of the controls, after sorting any of the columns, it resets the color of all my user controls to it's default (red).

After a few tests and research I think that the problem is that the DataGrid updates itself at the end of the item source and instanciates new User Controls instead of using the ones on my data object.

Is there anyway to solve this? I've tried a few solutions that I've found around the web and nothing worked so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume your class looks something like this...

```
 public class MyObject
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public int Status { get; set; }
     public UserControl StatusControl { get; }
 }
```

Is my assumptions correct?

If so, I have a few recommendations

1. Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) event and raise property chnaged notifications for Name, ID and Status properties.
2. Get rid of your `UserControl` type (i.e. `StatusControl`) property from your model (i.e. `MyObject` class)
3. Do not use `AutogenerateColumns` as true (which is by default true) on the datagrid. Create your specific columns...

   ```
    <tk:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False">
         <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
             <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                                    Binding="{Binding ID}" />
             <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}" />
             <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status"
                                        SortMemberPath="Status">
                 <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <ns:StatusControl>
                           <ns:StatusControl.Style>
                               <Style TargetType="{x:Type ns:StatusControl}">
                                   <Setter Property="IndicatorColor"
                                           Value="Green"/>
                                   <Style.Triggers>
                                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"
                                                    Value="1">
                                           <Setter Property="IndicatorColor"
                                                   Value="Red"/>
                                       </DataTrigger>
                                   </Style.Triggers>
                               </Style>                                           
                           </myNamespace:StatusControl.Style>
                       </myNamespace:StatusControl>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <tk:DataGrid>
   ```

Here your user control (like the `StatusControl`) should expose a `Brush` property (something like `IndicatorColor`) so that based on the Status, the `Fill` color of the Circle in the user control (see the `DataTrigger`) will change.

So this way as you receive updates on `Status` property of `MyObject` the `DataTrigger` will update the color on the user control.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I used your 2nd recomendation and got rid of my user control from my object, then I went cell by cell on that column and updated the status control one by one, and it works fine. However, when I sort any given column, it resets every control to its default fill(red). I know about the DataGrid.Sorting event, but it doesn't work. Is there other way to solve this??
If it matters, all columns are ReadOnly, don't know if it helps...
By the way, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @David, did you see what I have specified sort member path against the template column? It was excatly to solve for this problem you are telling me. Datagrid's sort takes place solely on the **data represented** by the cell and not on what cell **has or contains**. `SortMemberPath` is exclusively used by the sorting functionality of the datagrid. And as you have not used it, sorting wont take place the way you expect it to be.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Actually I saw that, but only after I posted my last comment :P. I was struggling a little with the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, but after I resolved it I went back here and pretty much copied your XAML code to mine. It works great!!!
Thanks a lot